# Nodejs for loop callback issues

Tags: javascript, nodes

I wrote this function that should run this for loop and then the callback at the end but it keeps running the callback before it finishes the loop. The only solutions I've read said using a callback would fix this issue but it doesn't seem to be making much of a difference.

```
function run(callback){
  for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
    request(url, function(error, resp, body){
      //uses cheerio to iterate through some elements on the page
      //then saves to an object for a future response  
    });
    callback();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is anything in "does some stuff" async?

Comment: Yes, there's a request that runs in the loop updating the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a variable called `totaltasks` and another one called `tasksfinished`. Then when a request is finished increment `tasksfinished`, and call your callback whenever `tasksfinished` equals `totaltasks`:

```
function run(callback){
  var totaltasks = urls.length;
  var tasksfinished = 0;

  // helper function
  var check = function() {
    if(totaltasks == tasksfinished) {
       callback();
    }
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < totaltasks; i++){
    try {
      request(url, function(error, resp, body) { 

        tasksfinished++;
        check();
     });
    } catch(e) {
      tasksfinished++;
      check();
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your callback function inside of the request callback:

```
function run(callback){
  for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
     request(url, function(error, resp, body){    
        //uses cheerio to iterate through some elements on the page
        //then saves to an object for a future response  
         callback();
     });

}
```

Comment: but when I do that it runs the callback as many times as the for loop, and I need the callback to fire when everything inside the for loop is completed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code example is missing some brackets. `request` is likely an asynchronous library. So at it's function call it's registering with the event loop and returns immediately. Meaning you actually call the callback immediately, probably without request having finished. So synchronously looping with async functions won't work.

Either use something like Promises, Continuation Passing, or register a variable, which tracks whether all calls have returned already.